# How to output SNS topic ARN created by CloudFormation to command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template which invokes a lambda function to create a SNS topic.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "AGS": {
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
        },
        "Secret": {
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+",
            "NoEcho": true
        },
        "SDLC": {
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "D",
                "I",
                "J",
                "Q",
                "S",
                "U",
                "P",
                "C"
            ]
        },
        "Component": {
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
        },
        "Topic": {
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
        },
        "TopicLambda": {
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "BRIDGE2ESBTOPIC": {
            "Type": "Custom::EnterpriseTopic",
            "Version": 1,
            "Properties": {
                "ServiceToken": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        ":",
                        [
                            "arn",
                            "aws",
                            "lambda",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                            },
                            "function",
                            {
                                "Ref": "TopicLambda"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "AGS": {
                    "Ref": "AGS"
                },
                "Secret": {
                    "Ref": "Secret"
                },
                "SDLC": {
                    "Ref": "SDLC"
                },
                "Component": {
                    "Ref": "Component"
                },
                "ResourceName": {
                    "Ref": "Topic"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    //This will only output to CloudFormation console, not to command line.
    "Outputs": {
        "Topic": {
            "Description" : "Topic created by this template",
            "Value": {"Ref": "BRIDGE2ESBTOPIC"}
        }
    }
}
```

After running the command in command line, I get response in command line like this:

```
> aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name stack3 --template-body file://template.json --parameters file://parameters.json      
{                                                                                                                                   
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:465257512377:stack/stack3/72747670-aa8b-11e6-85de-500c286e1a36"                    
}
```

The response only tells me the `StackId` just created. Is there any way to output the topic ARN just created by this CloudFormation template to command line? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Describe Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) with the query [option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html),  would be the most direct path.

#### Example

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks\
--stack-name yourStackIDName\
--query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[0].OutputValue'\
--output text
```

#### Your Example

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks\
--stack-name arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:465257512377:stack/stack3/72747670-aa8b-11e6-85de-500c286e1a36\
--query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[0].OutputValue'\
--output text
```

Answer (score 0):

After the stack gets created, you can use `aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name stack3`
That will display the output section (In your case Topic ARN)